# Couldn't find Book with 'id'=index Rails Ajax JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am currently trying to work with ajax and I this is the error I am getting.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /books/index. Couldn't find Book with 'id'=index

My Intention is that I want the cards of the Books to sort by themselves when I click on the Select and change the value without reloading. Therefore, I use js and ajax but currently I am still in the process.

Book Index.html.erb

```
<select id="priceSelect">
  <option value="Best Results" selected="selected">Best Results</option>
  <option value="Price Descending">Price Descending</option>
  <option value="Price Ascending">Price Ascending</option>
</select>

.
.
.

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 selectable-card">
    <%= link_to book_path(book.id) do %>
      ...   
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "books/index",
      type: "GET",
      data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
    })
  });
</script>
```

This is my BooksController.rb

```
before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  if params[:book][:title].present? && params[:users][:university].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})
  elsif !params[:users][:university].present? && params[:book][:title].present?
    @books = Book.where({title: params[:book][:title]})
  elsif params[:users][:university].present? && !params[:book][:title].present?
    @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params[:users][:university]})
  else
    @books = Book.all
  end

  case params[:sort]
    when "Price Descending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "DESC")
    when "Price Ascending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "ASC")
    else
      @books.sort_by(&:created_at)
  end
end
```

I really don't get why this error is appearing since I declared that this method should only work on [:show], etc... and not on [:index]. The error says that it's because of that that line here inside of my BooksController.

```
private

def set_book
 @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

And lastly my routes.rb

```
resources :books do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: You're passing it an ID of 'index' in the URL. Don't, it's not necessary. A GET request to the root books route in what you want.

Comment: You want to hit books index action in ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

> books/index

with just

> /books

Because by default `/books` will hit `index` action only. If you pass anything after `/books`  it will consider that as an id as mentioned in URL.

```
<script>
  $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/books",
      type: "GET",
      data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
    })
  });
</script>
```